# If Ionic crystals are heated up, where does the energy go?

Tags: thermodynamics, crystals

Ionic crystal are poor conductors of heat, due to lack of delocalised electrons. So if they are heard up where does the heat go? Does it get dumped in the potential well created by interatomic potentials? 
Or am I mistaken in thinking poor conductance means the crystal does not get hotter.

Comment: In general, heat conduction from electrons is mainly important at low temperatures.  At room temperature, the phonon contribution (@lemon's nuclei oscillating) dominates, even for metals.

Answer (score 1):

When you heat up an ionic crystal, the nuclei oscillate more quickly (increase in kinetic energy) and this causes the atoms to become more spaced apart, i.e. the material expands (increase in potential energy).

You can see this effect come out of the [virial stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_stress).